# realloc call fails and throws SIGABORT signal

Tags: c, linux, malloc, heap-memory, heap-corruption

My Program sometimes returns from this line of malloc.c file , I am not able to make out conclusion of comment and code .
This code is part of glibc-2.27 library of function __libc_realloc

https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/glibc-2.27/source/malloc/malloc.c#L3128

```
  /* Little security check which won't hurt performance: the allocator
     never wrapps around at the end of the address space.  Therefore
     we can exclude some size values which might appear here by
     accident or by "design" from some intruder.  We need to bypass
     this check for dumped fake mmap chunks from the old main arena
     because the new malloc may provide additional alignment.  */

  if ((__builtin_expect ((uintptr_t) oldp > (uintptr_t) -oldsize, 0)
       || __builtin_expect (misaligned_chunk (oldp), 0))
      && !DUMPED_MAIN_ARENA_CHUNK (oldp))
      malloc_printerr ("realloc(): invalid pointer");
```

Comment: The error is in your code. You most likely corrupt the dynamic memory heap by accessing to memory that you didn't allocate.

Comment: If you are looking for a specific reason why this would happen then we won't be able to help you without you showing a [mre] of your code which produces the above error. You are most likely passing an invalid pointer to `realloc()` *somehow...*

Comment: atleast explain me the meaning of comment and code , as its make little sense to me

Comment: @MarcoBonelli problem is it happened so rarely that i do not have any other information just a call trace from which i got this information ..